# How to use a flags enum as a property of a custom component in SSIS?

Tags: c#, ssis, enums

I'm programming a custom component for SSIS in which I need the following Enum as a property I can edit (selection of multiple values is needed).

```
[Flags]
public enum PermissionSettings : ushort
{
    None = 0,
    Groups = 1,
    ADGroups = 2,
    Users = 4,
    Owner = 8,
    OwnerGroup = 16,
    PublicAccess = 32,
    System = 64
}
```

So far I have achieved that I can select a single value for PermissionSettings in my custom component via a TypeConverter and setting the TypeConverter property of the custom SSIS property.
How can I enable selecting multiple properties?
Do I have to write a custom ui editor?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe you do have to write a custom UI.  The properties/property pages dialogs really only understand single-valued properties.  Take a look at the ReadOnlyVariables/ReadWriteVariables of the Script Component - they're stored as a comma-separated list of variables, not as an array.